# What is best to do when you are not sure about a Review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I was confronted lately to few *FirstPost/Late Answer Reviews* reviews where the reaction to take was not obvious.

After pondering between flagging or not, and I finally went for a *No Action Needed* while not being that sure.
(that lead me to a big ban, why I took time to ponder and formulate this question)

It happened for *Low Quality*, and *Spam* situation like. (in which it was not the *it's obvious it's shit* kind of post)

So what I wonder is how should I react when I feel like *seems not that bad, but I'm far from being 100% sure.*

- Is `Skip` intended for that use? I was seeing more as a *a have no Idea, no competence in this field*
- *Is it better to potentially falsely flag?* (had some spam declined, which counterbalanced the tendency to flag as spam that I learned with spam audit failed)
- Otherwise, where is the place to talk about this, if you want a second viewpoint to discuss with ?

Comment: `Skip` is _always_ the correct thing to do if you are unsure. If you post a link to what you are not sure about here, we can tell you what should be done with it. A few rejected spam flags are better than letting potential spam slip through imo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are unsure, do not hit the No action Needed. Just Skip it instead. Never take action on a review you are unsure of. If you feel there is something wrong but are unsure, you can ask for help on MSO or in an appropriate chat room.

- *have no Idea, no competence in this field* , then skip it. Let the people more familiar with it deal with it ( you should flag it only if you are sure )
- *is it better to potentially falsely flag?* , No, it's not.
- *where is the place to talk about this, if you want a second viewpoint to discuss with ?*, you can ask on MSO, or have a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) with the much more experienced users in an appropriate chat room.

So, if you are unsure, just skip. That is exactly what it is there for ( you can always review a skipped one later by checking in review History and hit the show skipped reviews at the bottom right corner ).

The skip button was made specially so that unsure users can skip it and not cause an outrage by making wrong reviews and then lamenting over failed audits on MSO.

You can find more details on

[There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

and an even better one on

[Should we **always** skip reviews when we are unfamiliar with the topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210539/should-we-always-skip-reviews-when-we-are-unfamiliar-with-the-topic)

Comment: than @arun for the feedback and the pointer on the two other posts. :)

Answer (score 8):

## If you're not sure, *skip*.

If you don't know what to do with a review, don't act as if you did!

The skip button is there for a reason. Not everyone has enough knowledge/experience to deal with all the reviews. Acting on reviews when you're not sure what should be done is counter-productive, please don't do that.